# Keep a Play 2 application private on heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, cloud

I'm using Heroku to host a Play 2 application for the purpose of testing and playing around. I'd like the application to be "private" at this point which means that every aspect of the application should only be visible to certain users.

Normally, I would just use an htaccess file with one single user/password, but that's a specific thing of Apache of course and doesn't help me in this case.

- The protection doesn't have to be "strong". The main aim is to keep away bots and random visitors
- It would be great if I didn't have to "pollute" the code of my play application. I'd prefer to have some external mechanism to achieve that. If there is no other way than to realize it using play itself, the solution should be loosely coupled from the rest of my play application.

How could I achieve that?

edit: to emphasize it: what I want to achieve won't be part of the final application in production mode. So it neither has to be super secure, nor super engineered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adreas example is correct but it is from play 2.1 and in play 2.2 the signature of Filter.apply has changed a little bit, this should work better with 2.2:

```
class BasicAuth extends Filter {

  val username = "stig"
  val password = "secretpassword"

  override def apply(next: RequestHeader => Future[SimpleResult])(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    request.headers.get("Authorization").flatMap { authorization =>
      authorization.split(" ").drop(1).headOption.filter { encoded =>
        new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encoded.getBytes)).split(":").toList match {
          case u :: p :: Nil if u == username && password == p => true
          case _ => false
        }
      }.map(_ => next(request))

    }.getOrElse {
      Future.successful(Results.Unauthorized.withHeaders("WWW-Authenticate" -> """Basic realm="MyApp Staging""""))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont think Heroku offers a solution for this. I ended up implementing a [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) filter and used it in the Global object. It looks something like this

```
class HerokuHttpAuth extends Filter {

  object Conf {
    val isStaging = true // read a config instead of hard coding
    val user = "theusername"
    val password = "thepassword"
  }

  override def apply(next: RequestHeader => Result)(request: RequestHeader): Result = {

    if (Conf.isStaging) {
      request.headers.get("Authorization").flatMap { authorization =>
        authorization.split(" ").drop(1).headOption.filter { encoded =>
          new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encoded.getBytes)).split(":").toList match {
            case u :: p :: Nil if u == Conf.user && Conf.password == p => true
            case _ => false
          }
        }.map(_ => next(request))

      }.getOrElse {
        Results.Unauthorized.withHeaders("WWW-Authenticate" -> """Basic realm="MyApp Staging"""")
      }
    } else {
      next(request)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks exactly like what I need! Unfortunately, I can't make it work. Is it possible to use Scala code in a Play Java app? I get this: `method apply overrides nothing. Note: the super classes of class HerokuHttpAuth contain the following, non final members named apply: def apply(next: play.api.mvc.EssentialAction): play.api.mvc.EssentialAction def apply(f: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader => scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult])(rh: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader): scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.SimpleResult]` Of  course I imported `play.api.mvc._`.

Comment: (the filter examples from the Play website don't work either, same error..)